# What is the phase difference between the reflected light and the transmitted light of the non-polarized beam splitting cube?

Tags: interference

We have consulted a lot of materials such as Optic by Hecht, but did not find the answer to this question. As shown in the figure, when light a enters the beam splitter, it produces beam b after reflection and beam c after transmission. What is the phase difference between the reflected light and the transmitted light of the non-polarized beam splitting cube[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts about this? It seems straightforward for the setup you have drawn. How does the beam splitter work though? Is it semi-silvered?

Comment: The splitting ratio of the beam splitter used is 50:50, the model is BS013, and the product link is https://www.thorlabschina.cn/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=BS013

Answer (score 0):

For a loss-less beam-splitter your question is answered by energy conservation.
Let $a^*$, $b^*$, $c^*$ be the EM-vectors of the in and out going radiation and $a=|a^*|$,$b=|b^*|$ and $c=|c^*|$. That yields
$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 \tag{Eq1}.$$
Adding up the EM radiation of both output channels and determining the energy flow of the combined radiation results in
$$a^2 = |b^*+c^*|^2 = (b^2 + 2\cos(p)\cdot bc + c^2) \tag{Eq2}.$$
Here $p$ is the phase shift between $b^*$ and $c^*$.
Comparing Eq2 with Eq1 shows, that the answer to question is $p = \pm \pi/2$.